# Why does my Meteor app error only publicly?

Tags: javascript, meteor

When I run my app locally, it works perfectly. When I deploy it, I get an error in the js console: `"Unexpected token <"`. The error refers me to my file `verifypwd.js`. Here's that file:

```
verifypwd = function(){
   console.log("Verifying");
   var inputPWD = document.getElementById("password").value;
   if(pwd.find({}).fetch()[0].pwd.indexOf(inputPWD) != -1){
     document.cookie = "allowed=true"
     window.location.pathname = "/main";
   }
   else {
    console.log("PWD Incorrect");
   }
}

logout = function(){
   document.cookie = "allowed=true; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC";
   window.location.pathname = "/";
}
```

What's wrong with this, and why does it only error when deployed?

Comment: I hope you realize that you're storing passwords on the server in cleartext and keeping your logged-in state in a cookie that anyone can set from the console. Neither are the source of your error however.

Comment: I do. And I hope to fix that. @MichelFloyd Give me the address of a tutorial on passwords in meteor

Comment: Using the accounts package is your best bet https://www.meteor.com/accounts

Comment: Please show the complete error including stacktrace if available. The token the error mentions doesn't even appear in this file, so the problem must lie elsewhere.

Comment: @ChristianFritz actually in Meteor this error can mean almost anything. It's not a syntax error like it says. Even if it was, why wouldn't it happen locally?